# Differential equation with two dependent variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, problem-solving

I have following differential equation -

$z'yx + y'zx + yz - ay'=0$

where, $y$ and $z$ both depend on $x$.

$y'= \frac{dy}{dx}$ and $z'= \frac{dz}{dx}$

$a$ is constant

I have to find $y(x)$ and $z(x)$. I have just this equation to work around a solution. Can I solve it? How to solve this differential equation with two dependent variables?

Any topic suggestion or hint will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You can rewrite the differential equation like so

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[xy(x)z(x) \right] = \dfrac{d}{dx}\left[ay(x)\right].$$

Integration will yield

$$xy(x)z(x) = ay(x) + c$$
$$\implies \left[xz(x)-a\right]y(x) = c.$$

**Edit** after additional information was provided:
If we know that $z(0)=y(0)=0$ then we can conclude

$$\left[0 \cdot z(0) - a\right]y(0) = c.$$
$$0 = c$$

This will imply

$$\left[xz(x)-a\right]y(x) = 0.$$

A product can only be zero if at least one of the terms is zero.

In total we can have the following conditions

- Only first term is $0$: $xz(x)-a = 0 \implies z(x)=a/x$ and $y(x)$ is arbitrary.
- Only second term is $0$: $y(x) = 0$ and $xz(x) - a$ is arbitrary.
- Both terms are $0$: $y(x) = 0$ and $z(x)=a/x$ (is included in the first case).

Comment: that's how I came up with this equation in the first place, from FOC wrt to x. That would take me back to my objective function.

Comment: @ElinaGilbert You cannot determine two unknown functions from one equation. Differentiating makes no sense.

Comment: Okay! So, it can't be solved. Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: You can just plug in any arbirtrary $z(x)$ and solve for $y(x)$. Not much to do.

Comment: Okay! Thanks again!! @MachineLearner

Comment: @ElinaGilbert Do you have any additional condition? Like $x=0, z(x=0)$ and $y(x=0)$?

Comment: I have y(0)=0 and z(0)=0. Will it be of any use?

Comment: @ElinaGilbert: I edited my answer. We can use $y(0)=z(0)=0$ to obtain more granular information.

Comment: Thanks @MachineLearner! Much help.